# How to prevent an alert run after the first run

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not good in HTML & JavaScript.

How can I prevent javascript running after the first run. Lets imagine *I loaded the first page and I went to another page from a link of it. IN THE FIRST PAGE THERE IS AN ALERT RUNNING BY JS. so when i came back to the first page the alert will be shown* HOW CAN I PREVENT THIS?

this is my code.(it just a little once)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function name(me)
    {
      document.write(me);
    }

    me=window.prompt("Enter your Name before Proceed");
    name(me);
</script>
```

Comment: How do you come back to the first page?

Comment: By wrapping it in some conditional check.  If the condition is true, execute the code, otherwise don't execute the code.  Now, what would your condition be?  What would you check to determine whether or not to execute the code?

Comment: Well, if it's really "another - distinct" page called, you can't only with javascript... You may use php sessions to keep data while navigating in pages of the same domain /app.

Comment: @Julo0sS: Sure you can, you just need to persist some piece of information somewhere.  Local storage, session storage, cookie, etc.

Comment: As @David says you could use a cookie. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: @David You're right, just meaning that without sessions / cookies / etc... not possible. Here he's asking "if user has already seen the prompt, then...", this way is not possible on distinct pages.

Comment: @Julo0sS: Well, sure.  If you arbitrarily restrict the toolset to not include anything which can do the job, then you can't do the job.  But I don't see why such a restriction would be assumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use localStorage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var me = localStorage.getItem("name");
    if (me == null)
    {
      me = window.prompt("Enter your Name before Proceed");
      localStorage.setItem("name", me);
    }
    document.write(me);
</script>
```

## Update

By using sessionStorage instead of localStorage, the data will be kept only for one session, meaning that if you close the browser window, the data will be forgotten. Maybe that is more appropriate?

Comment: Since sessionStorage is another option, I think you should explain the difference

Comment: Hey your code has worked great. But there is a small problem. After I open the html , add a name and close the browser the name wont forgot. when i open the html back, the name is still appearing. how can i prevent that? (I'm using google chrome)

Comment: Did you also try to use sessionStorage instead of localStorage?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to prompt on first visit, and not prompt on revisit would be to set the name using a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie).

```
   var me = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)me\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
   if ( !me ) {
     me = window.prompt('Enter your Name before Proceed');
     document.cookie = 'me='+me+'; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/';
   }
   name(me);
```

The first line checks if the name has already been stored in the cookie, and if nothing is returned then the prompt asks the user for their name which is then added to the cookie for future visits.

Comment: Will work if the user did not turn off cookies and not have a `;` in his/hers name.

Comment: The RegEx is directly from the Mozilla 'Cookie' documentation. It could probably be optimized more for this specific use case.